# How to solve the hyperlink problem in this Beamer TeX?

Tags: beamer, overlays, presentations, hyperlink

In this Beamer TeX when I click on `example-image-b` in intem2 I go to the image-b. But when I click on the image I will come back to the original slide but there is no item2. I want to item2 being in the slide when I come back to it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}        



\graphicspath{{./images/}}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\section{Section One}
\subsection{Subsection One}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\label{frm:Outline}

\begin{itemize}\addtolength{\itemsep}{1.5\baselineskip}
  \item   Item1, \hyperlink{frm:first_image}{example-image-a}
  \item <+(1)-> Item2, \hyperlink{frm:second_image}{example-image-b,} \hyperlink{frm:third_image}{example-image-c}
  \item <+(1)-> Item3

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[plain]
\label{frm:first_image}
     \centering
\hyperlink{frm:Outline}{%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight]{example-image-a}
}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\label{frm:second_image}
     \centering
\hyperlink{frm:Outline}{%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight]{example-image-b}
}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\label{frm:third_image}
     \centering
\hyperlink{frm:Outline}{%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight]{example-image-c}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to add new labels at the right points and jump to them.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}        

\begin{document}

\section{Section One}
\subsection{Subsection One}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\label{frm:Outline}

\begin{itemize}\addtolength{\itemsep}{1.5\baselineskip}
  \item   Item1, \hyperlink{frm:first_image}{example-image-a}
  \item <+(1)-> Item2, \hyperlink{frm:second_image}{example-image-b,}
  \hyperlink{frm:third_image}{example-image-c} 
  \label<+(1)->{frm:Outline-2}
  \item <+(1)-> Item3 
   \label<+(1)->{frm:Outline-3}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[plain]
\label{frm:first_image}
     \centering
\hyperlink{frm:Outline}{%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight]{example-image-a}
}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\label{frm:second_image}
     \centering
\hyperlink{frm:Outline-2}{%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight]{example-image-b}
}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\label{frm:third_image}
     \centering
\hyperlink{frm:Outline-2}{%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight]{example-image-c}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't do what I want.

Comment: I copy-paced yours but it does not do the job. When I click on the image-b I go back to the slide but the second item is not shown. I have to push a button to have second item shown. Also, third images is for item2, so I guess its hyperlink command should be before item3.

Comment: It works but, again, both "example-image-b" and "example-image-c" should be in Item2. In yours "example-image-c" is under Item3.

Comment: @user157323 You're welcome! And sorry for the misunderstanding!